# how to configure autocommit to true in flyway command line? (snowflake issue)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flyway, autocommit

we are having issues with autocommit set to false in flyway.
We need to set autocommit to true.

this is what we see in snowflake query activity: `alter session /* JDBC:SnowflakeConnectionV1.setAutoCommit*/ set autocommit=false`

I did not find any reference in the flyway documentation discussing how to do it in flyway command line tool.

I only found this topic, but it is using flyway JAVA API not for flyway CLI: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1534

Comment: You could try to setup [flyway.executionInTransaction=false](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/configfile) in the config file

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set autoCommit=false in the JDBC string. Keep in mind that whenever you run a DDL command (create an object) that this will automatically commit your transaction no matter how this setting is. See this [section](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#ddl) of the Snowflake documentation for more info.